# How to display line breaked meta values in table?

Tags: array

I have meta_key 'oyuncular' and it has meta values with line breaks. I want to get them and display in table with two column. Name and Role Name

[image]

```
$names = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'oyuncular', true );
$namesArray = explode( '\n', $names);

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr class="table-success">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Role Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php

        foreach( $namesArray as $key => $name ) { ?>

            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Role Name</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `explode()` or `preg_split()`, like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $namesArray as $key => $name ) {
    $arr = explode( ' -', $name, 2 );
    //$arr = preg_split( '/\s+\-/', $name, 2 );

    $name2 = isset( $arr[0] ) ? trim( $arr[0] ) : '';
    $role_name = isset( $arr[1] ) ? trim( $arr[1] ) : '';

    if ( $name2 || $role_name ) : $i++; ?>

    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $name2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $role_name; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php endif;
}
```

Also, you need to wrap the `\n` in double-quotes:

```
$namesArray = explode( "\n", $names); // not '\n'
```

Otherwise, the `\n` will not be evaluated as "new line".